# Can i access python function inside in same function?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, python-3.x

Can i access python **function** inside in **same function or sub function of main function**?

```
def main_function():
   def sub_function():
       main_function() # i need to call main function.can i or not.any solution?
```

NameError: name 'main_function' is not defined

Comment: A general question, why would you need a function to declare another function? I don't see the application of this

Comment: @lightandlight This is a standard practice. It is used for decorators and the python standard library are full of instances of it.

Comment: @lightandlight One reason is that you can use nonlocal variables inside the inner function, or even retain references to them via "closure".  Another is simply for namespacing, so the function doesn't leak out of the local namespace.  Another is if you want the function definition itself to be procedural in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, yes.

I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted.  But, it will not actually do anything, because you can only call `sub_function` from within `main_function` and currently you are only defining `sub_function` but not actually calling it.  If you got a `NameError` somehow, despite your code not actually executing anything in any real way, there must be some other reason.

If you do it like this, which is similar to what you did except it adds an actual call to `sub_function` inside `main_function`:

```
def main_function():
   def sub_function():
       main_function()
   sub_function()
```

and then you call `main_function()`, you will get a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error, because it is an infinitely recursing function.

Comment: Thanks....i think i understand my fault.i want restart my program that's why i recall main_function.by the way i find another solution.i think using while loop can fulfill my requirement.